# Test value between x and y

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two `data.frame`s, one with the value "size" to test and the other has the interval N1 to N2 to test. If it's the case, so it will print TRUE into a new column "test"

Comment: try to think about your interval, it have overlap for example :`ID1 1126    1472
ID1 1386    1413`

Comment: Also `1455    ID2 TRUE` should be `1455    ID2 FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `data.table`'s non-equi join:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Df1)
setDT(Df2)

Df1[, test := FALSE]

Df1[Df2, test := TRUE, on = .(ID, size >= N1, size <= N2)]
# > Df1
#    size  ID  test
# 1:  399 ID1  TRUE
# 2:  887 ID2  TRUE
# 3:  350 ID1  TRUE
# 4: 1400 ID2 FALSE
# 5: 1455 ID2 FALSE
# 6: 1700 ID2 FALSE
# 7: 1654 ID1 FALSE
# 8:  928 ID1 FALSE
# 9: 1228 ID1  TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure, do you want TRUE/FALSE be based if size from Df1 is within N1 and N2 from Df2? If so you could use %between% from data.table.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "size    ID
                   399     ID1
                  887     ID2
                  350     ID1
                  1400    ID2
                  1455    ID2
                  1700    ID2
                  1654    ID1
                  928     ID1
                  1228    ID1", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID  N1      N2
ID1 298     500
                  ID1 560     706
                  ID1 809     925
                  ID1 959     1195
                  ID1 1126    1472
                  ID1 1386    1413
                  ID2  800    950
                  ID2 1074    1203
                  ID2 1462    1486
                  ID2 1542    1658", header = T)
```

`library(data.table)`

```
df1$Test <- ifelse(df1$size %between% c(df2$N1, df2$N2), TRUE, FALSE)
```

This answer does not return what you expect though, as I dont really understand what the TRUE/FALSE should be based on.